# Using the LinkedIn API in a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, linkedin-api

I'm building a small Windows Forms application and I want to access information from the company search API. I don't even want to write anything to the profile.

I've gotten as far as opening a web browser and asking my user to type in some verification code into my application.

This is so incredibly frustrating! There's tons of sample code out there for Python and Java, but .NET just has some half baked *working* demos that don't even build properly.

I need your help.

I've already seen the official [LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/), but the project doesn't even build!

So I went ahead and downloaded the LinkedIn.dll library that supposedly acts as the wrapper for accessing the data.

How can I access the API using it? I already have an API key and a secret token key, both saved in my App.config file waiting to be used.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the build error you are getting?

Comment: You know you can use IRON Python? Try those examples and see how you get on.

Comment: Try downloading and adding reference to DotNetOpenAuth http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 1):

You might check out the examples linked to from the [Libraries and Tools](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools) page on the LinkedIn Developer Portal.  The "Working C# example" posted by one of our community members works well...

https://developer.linkedin.com/sites/default/files/LinkedInAuth.rar.zip

We have a few other C# examples as well, but this should get you started - it has an example of getting an access token and making a request.

Comment: Its not available now, can u plz provide another working link

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the [LinkedInNET lib on github](https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET). The API coverage is not full but it's growing.

There is a NuGet package

```
PM> Install-Package Sparkle.LinkedInNET
```

You will have the challenge of authenticating your user within your winforms app though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get used to the `OAuth` authorization mechanism. It essentially makes the user go to the linkedin website, signin and allow your application to access their data from linked in.

It is briefly described in the [documentation for the LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Authorization&referringTitle=Documentation). Look into the `WebOAuthAuthorization` class. It's really small and has two important methods:

- `BeginAuthorize(Uri callback)`
- `CompleteAuthorize()`

The Former method sends the user to linkedin website for authorization. The callback parameter is used by linked in to notify your website about the result of the authorization. At that point you must call the `CompleteAuthorization()` method for your application to finish establishing a session with linked in for this particular user.